# get max duplicate item in list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have this list:

```
mylist = [20, 30, 25, 20, 30]
```

After getting the duplicated values indexes using

```
[i for i, x in enumerate(mylist) if mylist.count(x) > 1]
```

the result is:

```
`[0, 1, 3, 4]`
```

having two pairs of duplicated values. I'd like to know, how can i get only the higher duplicated value? In this list it is `30` or any of it's indexes, `1` or `4`, instead of the whole list of duplicated values.

Regards...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one is O(n)

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> mylist = [20, 30, 25, 20, 30]
>>> max(k for k,v in Counter(mylist).items() if v>1)
30
```

Comment: Based on [these timings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11256412/298607), this is the slowest solution posted. [Ned Batchelder's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11255051/298607) is 5X faster.

Answer (score 5):

Getting the maximum duplicated value:

```
max(x for x in mylist if mylist.count(x) > 1)
```

This has O(n**2) performance because of the repeated count() calls, unfortunately.  Here's a wordier way to do the same thing that will have O(n) performance, important if the list is long:

```
seen = set()
dups = set()
for x in mylist:
    if x in seen:
        dups.add(x)
    seen.add(x)
max_dups = max(dups)
```

Comment: That is not O(n); that is O(n*log(n)); the same as with sorting

Comment: @IgorChubin Python uses a hash table for sets. Insertion and lookup is on average in O(1). I'm not sure if max is O(1) or O(n). I did not find a documentation if max is optimized for dicts. Either way: This algorithm should work in O(n).

Comment: @kay: Why do you think that lookup in a set is O(1) and not O(log n)?

Comment: @IgorChubin Average lookup time is O(1) and worst case is O(N) where all hashed values collide.

Comment: @jamylak: (@kay, @NedBatchelder) You are right, that was my fault

Comment: Based on [these timings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11256412/298607), this is the your second solution is the FASTEST one posted...

Answer (score 1):

Another O(n) way of doing it, just because...

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> mylist = [20,30,25,20,30]
>>> dd = defaultdict(int)
>>> for i in mylist:
...    dd[i] += 1
...
>>> max(i for i in dd if dd[i] > 1)
30
```

You can also do it using a regular old dict:

```
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(mylist, 0)
>>> for i in mylist:
...   d[i] += 1
... 
>>> max(i for i in d if d[i] > 1)
30
```

Comment: Interesting how you have used `fromkeys` instead of the `setdefault` which is the usual alternate approach to `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 1):

Just some relative timings to consider:

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict

mylist = [20, 30, 25, 20, 30]

def f1():
    seen = set()
    dups = set()
    for x in mylist:
        if x in seen:
            dups.add(x)
        seen.add(x)
    max_dups = max(dups)

def f2():
    max(x for x in mylist if mylist.count(x) > 1)

def f3():
    max(k for k,v in Counter(mylist).items() if v>1)

def f4():
    dd = defaultdict(int)
    for i in mylist:
        dd[i] += 1

    max(i for i in dd if dd[i] > 1)

def f5():
    d = dict.fromkeys(mylist, 0)            
    for i in mylist:
       d[i] += 1

    max(i for i in d if d[i] > 1)

cmpthese([f1,f2,f3,f4,f5])
```

prints:

```
   rate/sec     f3     f4     f5     f2     f1
f3   93,653     -- -63.3% -73.0% -79.2% -83.6%
f4  255,137 172.4%     -- -26.3% -43.3% -55.3%
f5  346,238 269.7%  35.7%     -- -23.1% -39.3%
f2  450,356 380.9%  76.5%  30.1%     -- -21.0%
f1  570,419 509.1% 123.6%  64.7%  26.7%     --
```

So choose wisely

Comment: This is an old answer but it should be mentioned that it uses is an incredibly small initial list to draw broad conclusions on which algorithm is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat /tmp/1.py
from itertools import groupby

def find_max_repeated(a):
    a = sorted(a, reverse = True)
    for k,g in groupby(a):
        gl = list(g)
        if len(gl) > 1:
            return gl[0]

a = [1,1,2,3,3,4,5,4,6]
print find_max_repeated(a)

$ python /tmp/1.py
4
```

Comment: Maybe you could add some explanation … (after all this is a Q&A site.)

Comment: The use of `sorted` makes this O(n log n)

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [20, 30, 25, 20, 30]
result = max((mylist.count(x), x) for x in set(mylist))
print(result)
>>> (2, 30)
```

Here is how it works:

- set(mylist) - you create only unique values from the mylist 
  (20, 30, 25)
- then using the generator comprehension you create tuples with first item number of times that value occured 
  ((1, 25), (2, 20), (2, 30))
- since tuples are comparable item by item you can get max tuple in the sequence, which in this case (2, 30) because it's greater than (2, 20)